# Cannot install yolox

Tags: python, ubuntu, yolo

I am trying to install Yolox using the following command:

```
pip install yolox
```

I got this command from the following link:

https://pypi.org/project/yolox/

I got the following error:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error

 error: subprocess-exited-with-error


  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

  │ exit code: 1

  ╰─> [8 lines of output]

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>

    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>

    File "/tmp/pip-install-e8uz9eo5/yolox_dd607ece87a3411aabef0d9d5bff591a/setup.py", line 77, in <module>

      install_requires=get_install_requirements(),

    File "/tmp/pip-install-e8uz9eo5/yolox_dd607ece87a3411aabef0d9d5bff591a/setup.py", line 49, in get_install_requirements

      with open("requirements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:

  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

  [end of output]


 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 error: metadata-generation-failed


  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
  ╰─> See above for output.

 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
 hint: See above for details.
```

How can I solve this problem?
I should mention that I am installing this package on a remote machine based on ubuntu.

Comment: You don't need to reply if you don't know the answer. It is something related to the machine and my Ubuntu, not the package. Please delete your comment and let me find my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the error.

It was because of the Python version.

On Python3.10 this package is not working correctly.

Therefore I changed it to Python3.9 and it worked fine.